# Open a numeric keyboard without forcing the EditText to be numeric only

Tags: android, android-keypad

I've come across this while doing work on creating my own `Keyboard` but can't for the life of me remember where I ran across it.

I want top open the Numeric keyboard. However, I want my `EditText` to only accept an IP address. Adding a filter to my `EditText` wasn't too hard thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798188/726954).

However, now I want to make the Numeric keyboard to open rather than the standard text keyboard. Unfortunately search results are saturated with the same "How do you limit `EditText` to numeric input?" questions over and over.

Could anyone point me to the right place for manually opening the Numeric Keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I use `android:inputType="phone"`.

Comment: Well, it certainly works. Would prefer the standard number keyboard rather than the phone keyboard though (There is a way to do it).

Answer (score 2):

8 days late but alrighty!

```
android:inputType="number"
```

works for me. Of course Glitch's answer might be better given that not all keyboards have a numeric input style. And of course you'll still have to validate it

Comment: Doesn't work - forces a number to be input (ie, 1.0.0.1 is invalid)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the existing solution, if you want to restrict to *just* numbers and dots, you can add

```
android:digits="0123456789."
```

to the xml of the EditText. So combining the current solution and the above:

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789."
```

will make sure you are able to *just* put IP address related stuff in the EditText. Now, when the keyboard comes up it has the T9 letters on the keys, but that's a function of the "phone" inputType. Also, you'll have to make sure it's a valid IP after entry.

Answer (score 0):

or you can also go for

```
editext ss;
ss.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Doesn't work - forces a number to be input (ie, 1.0.0.1 is invalid)

Comment: it does  i think u have not find its id ( edittext id)  may be @Graeme