# Opening the numpad of the device

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a numeric keyboard without forcing the EditText to be numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476490/open-a-numeric-keyboard-without-forcing-the-edittext-to-be-numeric-only)

In my app i have an EditText field which accepts only integer values. so i thought it would be better to open the numpad automatically instead of the alphabetics when i click on this EditText.

```
How can i achieve this??
```

Comment: first try to search before post answer http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]open+numeric+keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xml file when defining your EditText, you add your inputType as Number

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml layout attributes

For this, you can use several xml attributes to your EditText xml definition (see [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) for available options)

Examples:

```
<EditText android:inputType="phone" ...
<EditText android:inputType="number" ...
<EditText android:inputType="numberSigned" ...
<EditText android:inputType="numberDecimal" ...
```

You can also both hint android to show digital keyboard and restrict input to acceptable characters with android:numeric

Examples:

```
<EditText android:numeric="integer" ...
<EditText android:numeric="signed" ...
<EditText android:numeric="decimal" ...
```

Programatically

Use `EditText.setRawInputType(int)` with constants such as TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER you will find in android:inputType

or

```
EditText editView = new EditText(this);
editView.setKeyListener(new NumberKeyListener())

EditText editView = new EditText(this);
editView.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener());
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

See `TextView` Documentation as `EditText` extends from it :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AutoCompleteTextView_inputType