# Can someone help me with the parameters to the Android InputFilter "filter" method? (plus regex)

Tags: java, android, regex, ip, mask

Please someone can explain to me the purpose of the source and dest parameters in [`android.text.InputFilter#filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)?

I tried to read the docs but I am really confused. I am trying to use a regex to make an IP mask. Any help is appreciated.

I get it now. So, for example, if I have 123.42, then the user types 123.42d, I will have:

```
dest = 123.42  
source = 123.42d  
start = 5  
end = 6

InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() 
    {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned  dest, int dstart, int dend) 
        {               
            String destTxt = dest.toString();
            String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) +                           source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);                

            if(resultingTxt.equals("")) return "";

            int lastChar = resultingTxt.length() -1;

            if(String.valueOf(resultingTxt.charAt(lastChar)).matches("[^0-9.]"))
            {
                return "";
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
```

This isn't working though. Shouldn't this return me only the digits? It happens that depending on what the user type it returns me characters too.

Comment: what is that "CharSequencer filter method" you are referring to? Is there any API-doc / or at least the method declaration?

Comment: The one when you instantiate a new InputFilter. I forgot to add that to the question, sorry.

Comment: Heres the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798140/press-many-times-validate-ip-address-in-edittext-while-typing should be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I already read this. It works so good. The problem is: I don't understand those parameters. Just want to understand them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have an `EditText` and you assign an `InputFilter` to it, then everytime you change the text in there the `filter()` method will be called. Much like the `onClick()` method of a button.

Let's say you had the text "Hello Androi" in your EditText before editing it. If you press 
the `D` key on your virtual keyboard then the inputfilter is triggered and basically asked if it is ok to add a `d`.

In that case `source` is "Android", start is 6, end is 7 - That is your reference to the new Text.

`dest` would be "Androi" and refers to the old text in your `EditText`

So you get the new String and a position in that string (the 6,7) that you have to check if it is okay. If you would just get a single character (like the `d`) you could not decide if e.g. the number you just entered forms an ip adress. You need the whole text as a context in some cases.

If the new text is ok as is return `null`, if you want to skip a change return empty String (`""`), otherwise return the characters that replace the change.

So a simple example might be that:

```
/**
 * Simplified filter that should make everything uppercase
 * it's a demo and will probably not work
 *  - based on InputFilter.AllCaps
 */
public static class AllCaps implements InputFilter {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        // create a buffer to store the edited character(s).
        char[] v = new char[end - start];

        // extract the characters between start and end into our buffer
        TextUtils.getChars(source, start, end, v, 0);

        // make the characters uppercase
        String s = new String(v).toUpperCase();

        // and return them
        return s;
    }
}
```

It's replacing every change with the uppercase version of it.