# EditText repeat text in Samsung Galaxy S3 Tab

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers, repeat

Let me come to point directly, I have one edit text in XML file as follows.

```
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_brand_name_add_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_img_banner"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relative_img_banner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_img_banner"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_login_page"
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_ "
            android:hint="Brand Name"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            app:fontName="fonts/Roboto_Light.ttf" />
```

In Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 if I type any number in EditText it will repeat all text already typed. E.g if EditText has values "tt" and if I try to type any number it will repeat "tt" as many time as you type any number. What should be the issue. It is working fine in other devices like Nexus 5 or HTC.

Comment: This problem might be related to limiting input characters (android:digits="abcd..") in Samsung devices. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178059/edittext-input-filter-causing-repeating-letters#comment57225277_16184550

Answer (score -1):

1. Restart your device
2. Restart IDE if it is eclipse
3. ReInstall application

if not solved  contact with your device manufacturer

Comment: if restarting the device or Restarting the IDE could have solved my problem i wouldn't have post my question here.