# android edittext minmum and maximum value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, max, min

I am in development of an android app.. actually i need to set a minimum and maximum value for an editext entry my minimum value is 18 and maximum is 65.I did the exact code of this

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}




EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "12")});
```

I got this  code fro this site only ...
[Is there a way to define a min and max value for EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-any-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android)
 actually this for values between 1 and 12 and for that value it is working fine but when i changed for my value 18 and 45 it is not working ... can anyone please help me.. what change i have to be done for this ...

Comment: try logging the values or try debugger mmode.

Comment: did you try answer from itsrajesh4uguys in the link you have given...that solution is good and worked for me...

Comment: thanks jeet for commenting... let me try ..

Comment: oh..jeet its not working ... i think i need to do some more code for that..but i dont have much experience in anrid coding..

Comment: this solution doesn't work for large number, lets say years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the line:

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
```

With

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(source.toString());
```

Look at [Can someone help me with the parameters to the Android InputFilter "filter" method? (plus regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815433/can-someone-help-me-with-the-parameters-to-the-android-inputfilter-filter-meth) to understand why

Comment: no ..its not working... because when i enter the two numbers 18 and 65 it is not working.. but it works fine for the first number between 1 -9 after it wont work like for ex if minimum value is 10 then it will not work ... we will not able to type the first letter1 ... that is the problem..

Comment: I think that you should have the minimum bound always set to 0. Otherwise, if the number you want is between 40 and 120, for example, then no number would be accepted since if you want the number 100 and you start pressing '1','0','0' any correct filter would not even accept the first digit since it is not above 40

Comment: thanks androidcompile any way i put your reply as answer eventhouggh it is not working... thanks for u r intrest to reply 4 me.. thanks a lot...