# InputFilter or TextWatcher for EditText which handle large integer(like year..)

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, largenumber

I need to make handler for EditText in my app and this EditText accept year between 1980 till 2015.

I've found a very good solution for EditText for day(s) and month(s) in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621210/android-edittext-minmum-and-maximum-value).

But Unfortunately it doesn't work for large numbers like years!

So i've wrote a piece of code.

```
etDateYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year_date_xml);
etDateYear.addTextChangedListener(YearWatcher);
private final TextWatcher YearWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            if(s.length()>=4){
                 int year = Integer.parseInt(etDateYear.getText().toString());
                 if(!(year < 2016 && year > 1979)) {
                     etDateYear.setText("");
                 }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            //nfe
        }

    }

};
```

This one also not work because any one digit is less than 1980 so it pass "". (I think it's the cause).

So anyone could help? Thank a lot..

Comment: 1)Simple solution replace "or" with "and" in the conditional expression. 2)Replace single if with two if condition. 3)Show the input filter code

Comment: Thanks for your consideration; I made what I've get from your comment but not... work :(

Comment: I guess you took the code of input filter from somewhere but did not modified it as per your requirement?

Comment: Yes and I've mentioned in my description with LINK. That InputFilter works well for day and month. please read my description carefully.

Comment: For future consideration please don't delete the code with issue and replace it with correct answer, place your fixed code below your problem. I felt really stupid because I saw no difference between your "problem" and what people suggested to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: The simplest solution I was mentioning is -**

```
if(s.length()>=4){
  int year = Integer.parseInt(etDateYear.getText().toString());
 if(year < 2015 && year > 1980 ) {
     //do nothing input is proper
 } else { 
   etDateYear.setText("");       
 }
```

}

or

```
if(s.length()>=4){
 int year = Integer.parseInt(etDateYear.getText().toString());
 if(!(year < 2015 && year > 1980)) {
         etDateYear.setText("");   
 }
}
```

**Solution 2: Using multiple if's**

```
if(s.length()>=4){
 int year = Integer.parseInt(etDateYear.getText().toString());
 if(year>1980){
   if(year<2015){
     //proper input
   } else {
     etDateYear.setText("");
   }
 } else {
  etDateYear.setText("");
 }
}
```

Comment: Delete 2 comments and please add the complete logcat report to the question itself...Also if you are using the textwatcher then remove the input filter.

Comment: Instead of setText() to " " I've change it to some character , and i wonder when i tap at any digit that character appear at EditText. Yours and mine IF(s) are true but always any digit I've add to EditText surly less that 1980 and this is my problem here. Hope i could describe it well to ya.

Comment: the Other things is InputFilter is other things and I didn't attach it to this Year EditText, I've just want to show the InputFilter which works for 1~99.

Comment: Please try the modified answer. I have tested it on Edit Text. As of now use Text Watcher. Bcoz with Input Filter it needs modification and you also need to use onFocusChange

Comment: Yes, Finally Its Working. Thank a lot. (my mistake was ignoring that length that you've added. Again TnX ;)