# EditText text formatting for forms

Tags: android, text, formatting, android-edittext

I'm looking for a simple way for Android, when a user taps a in a edit text box, it will add a hyphen inbetween the number set. Sort of like a phone number, but will be set in a custom position.

For example Book number 05, CD number 15, track number5 =  0515-5.  So when they start typing, the app will automatically enter the hyphen.

Should I use some type of listener and count how many characters are entered, then when it hits that number of characters, it will add the hyphen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [**InputFilter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html).

See my answers here: [press "." many times (validate ip address in EditText while typing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798140/press-many-times-validate-ip-address-in-edittext-while-typing/5798188#5798188) and here: [How to set Edittext view allow only two numeric values and two decimal values like ##.##](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736833/how-to-set-edittext-view-allow-only-two-numeric-values-and-two-decimal-values-lik/5738176#5738176) for ideas on how to implement it

Comment: This helped me out tremendously! Thank you!