# getting phone number in XXX-XXX-XXXX format from edittext box in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

Hi
I am writing an android in which user enters phone number in an edit text box.
I want the number to be in the form of xxx-xxx-xxxx that means '-' should come automatically after user enters first 3 letters and another '-'

I used `EditText anum= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.altnum);
        anum.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());`

but it is coming into format only after all the digits are entered. I want the change to come when the user was entering the data like if he press 123 a hypen should come automatically
Please tell me how to do this.

Thanking You

Yours Sincerely

ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to implement your own [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html).

You can use my answers here: [press "." many times (validate ip address in EditText while typing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798140/press-many-times-validate-ip-address-in-edittext-while-typing/5798188#5798188) and here: [How to set Edittext view allow only two numeric values and two decimal values like ##.##](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736833/how-to-set-edittext-view-allow-only-two-numeric-values-and-two-decimal-values-lik/5738176#5738176) for examples on how to parse the text while typing.

If you want the dashes to appear automatically, you will need to add them to the return of your filter method

Answer (score 9):

Recently, I had a requirement for the same. I tried this with TextWatcher. Sharing here with a hope that Someone else may need later.

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String TAG = PhoneNumberTextWatcher.class
        .getSimpleName();
private EditText edTxt;
private boolean isDelete;

public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(EditText edTxtPhone) {
    this.edTxt = edTxtPhone;
    edTxt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                isDelete = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (isDelete) {
        isDelete = false;
        return;
    }
    String val = s.toString();
    String a = "";
    String b = "";
    String c = "";
    if (val != null && val.length() > 0) {
        val = val.replace("-", "");
        if (val.length() >= 3) {
            a = val.substring(0, 3);
        } else if (val.length() < 3) {
            a = val.substring(0, val.length());
        }
        if (val.length() >= 6) {
            b = val.substring(3, 6);
            c = val.substring(6, val.length());
        } else if (val.length() > 3 && val.length() < 6) {
            b = val.substring(3, val.length());
        }
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(a);
            if (a.length() == 3) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
            }
        }
        if (b != null && b.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(b);
            if (b.length() == 3) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
            }
        }
        if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(c);
        }
        edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        edTxt.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        edTxt.setSelection(edTxt.getText().toString().length());
        edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } else {
        edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        edTxt.setText("");
        edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

}
 }
```

Thanks

JRH

Comment: solution is not working! it stuck at `-` while deleting.

Comment: @RobinHood, Can you please share the code you tried out ? Meanwhile, please have a look at the sample, which I tried. https://www.dropbox.com/s/72w2kojffb39y37/TestPhoneNumWatcher.zip

Comment: @Robinhood, Did you try the sample, which I shared ? please accept answer, if that works for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jrhamza : your zip file code is also not working. its same as you wrote.. it cant delete from - .

Comment: 1.Yes, when deleting at character "-" stucked
2.when i place cursor any where in middle and delete any character that character delete and cursor moves to last.this also should not happen.

Comment: Hi all, I have tested the shared project using 4.4.2 android and Tested in HTC Desire V ( 4.0.3). It is working fine.

Comment: @Bhanu, Can you please share the OS and device details ?

Comment: Anyone has found solution of stuck??

Comment: @AditiParikh, Can you please share the code? The pasted code was working for me. Not tested in the latest versions.

Answer (score 6):

Following Code works adding and deleting scenario's fine but logic is some what longer :

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneNumberTextWatcher";
private EditText editText;

public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(EditText edTxtPhone) {
    this.editText = edTxtPhone;
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int cursorPosition, int before,
                          int count) {

    if(before == 0 && count == 1){  //Entering values

        String val = s.toString();
        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        String c = "";
        if (val != null && val.length() > 0) {
            val = val.replace("-", "");
            if (val.length() >= 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, 3);
            } else if (val.length() < 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, val.length());
            }
            if (val.length() >= 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, 6);
                c = val.substring(6, val.length());
            } else if (val.length() > 3 && val.length() < 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, val.length());
            }
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append(a);

            }
            if (b != null && b.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
                stringBuffer.append(b);

            }
            if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
                stringBuffer.append(c);
            }
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            if(cursorPosition == 3 || cursorPosition == 7){
                cursorPosition = cursorPosition+2;
            }else{
                cursorPosition = cursorPosition+1;
            }
            if(cursorPosition <= editText.getText().toString().length()) {
                editText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
            }else{
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        } else {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }

    if(before == 1 && count == 0){  //Deleting values

        String val = s.toString();
        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        String c = "";

        if (val != null && val.length() > 0) {
            val = val.replace("-", "");
            if(cursorPosition == 3){
                val = removeCharAt(val,cursorPosition-1,s.toString().length()-1);
            }else if(cursorPosition == 7){
                val = removeCharAt(val,cursorPosition-2,s.toString().length()-2);
            }
            if (val.length() >= 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, 3);
            } else if (val.length() < 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, val.length());
            }
            if (val.length() >= 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, 6);
                c = val.substring(6, val.length());
            } else if (val.length() > 3 && val.length() < 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, val.length());
            }
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append(a);

            }
            if (b != null && b.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
                stringBuffer.append(b);

            }
            if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
                stringBuffer.append(c);
            }
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            if(cursorPosition == 3 || cursorPosition == 7){
                cursorPosition = cursorPosition-1;
            }
            if(cursorPosition <= editText.getText().toString().length()) {
                editText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
            }else{
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        } else {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }



}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


}

public static String removeCharAt(String s, int pos,int length) {

    String value = "";
    if(length > pos){
        value = s.substring(pos + 1);
    }
    return s.substring(0, pos)+value ;
}
}
```