# Extracting Floating Numbers From String Using Matcher and Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Suppose

```
String str="123 abc 123.4 256";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(scan);
while (m.find()) 
{
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

By Using this code i am getting output as:

```
123
123
4
256
```

But in output i want it as 123 ,`123.4`,256. What pattern should i use to get desirable result or what are the other solution beside using Matcher And pattern.

Comment: You need the right regular expression, a quick google seach relealed [following result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754552/regex-to-find-a-float-probably-a-really-simple-question), here is a [better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: `\\d+\\.\\d+` that's the apttern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex only looks for digits (the plus just means at least one). If you want decimals, you need to include the dot in the correct place

```
(\\d+\\.\\d+)
```

That will give you at least one digit, followed by a dot, followed by at least one digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pattern to match 123.4: \d+\.\d*

```
 String str="123 abc 123.4 256";
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d*").matcher(str);
      while (m.find()) 
      {
          System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
```

Comment: i assume d* says 0 or more, but will this give 123 as output??

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html 
there are couple of good examples.